# Seeking an "intuitive" proof

Tags: intuition

Consider the following claim.

> Let $a_i$'s and $y_i$'s be positive real numbers such that:
> \begin{gather*}
> y_1 \leq y_2 \leq y_3 \ldots \leq y_n \\
> a_1 y_1 + a_2 y_2 + a_3 y_3 + \dots + a_n y_n = v \\
> y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + \dots + y_n = 1
> \end{gather*}
> Show that there exists an $i$ such that:
> $$AVG(a_i, a_{i+1}, a_{i+2}, \ldots, a_n) \geq v.$$

I do have a proof for the above claim (assume the contrary; get $n$ equations; multiply $i^{th}$ equation by $y_{i+1} - y_i$). But, I'm looking for a more intuitive explanation — perhaps, a more "visual" or more insightful proof. Or even insights into why the above is true (without actually proving it).

Comment: What if $y_{i+1} - y_i$ is negative? Or are you assuming that $y_1 \leq \cdots \leq y_n$? Indeed, if $n = 2$, $y_1 = 1$, $y_2 = 0$, $a_1 = v = 3$ and $a_2 = 1$ then $a_2 < v$ and $(a_1 + a_2)/2 < v$. (If you don't like zeroes, change it to $y_1 = 1-\epsilon$ and $y_2 = \epsilon$.)

Comment: You can think of $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ as specifying a probability distribution, with respect to which $\mathbb{E}[a_i] = v$.

Comment: @Brian The claim is incorrect if you allow for $y$'s and $a$'s to be $0$. So your proof will *have* to somehow use the fact $a_i,y_i>0$

Comment: Yes, $y_1 \leq y_2 \leq y_3 \ldots \leq y_n$ is indeed true. I didn't realize that the proof was using it (it is) -- that's why hadn't added to the problem description. The $a_i$'s and $y_i$'s can be zero -- in fact, $a_n$ is actually zero (in the context where the above claim is coming from).

Comment: Why is this in CS rather than [math.se]?

Comment: This comes from an LP approximation proof. In particular, its my version of the proof of Lemma 2 from this paper (optimal algorithm for Densest subgraph using an LP): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.1184&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 4):

Since the $y_i$ are non-negative, you can think of $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ as specifying a probability distribution. One way to sample from this distribution is via the partition
$$
[0,1) = [0,y_1) \cup [y_1,y_1+y_2) \cup [y_1+y_2,y_1+y_2+y_3) \cup \cdots:
$$
sample a uniform point in $[0,1]$, and if it falls into the $i$'th interval, output $i$.

We now further decompose these intervals, assuming that $y_1 \leq \cdots \leq y_n$:

- The interval $[0,y_1)$ is decomposed into one subinterval of length $y_1$.
- The interval $[y_1,y_1+y_2)$ is decomposed into subintervals of length $y_1$ and $y_2-y_1$.
- The interval $[y_1+y_2,y_1+y_2+y_3)$ is decomposed into subintervals of length $y_1,y_2-y_1,y_3-y_2$.
- And so on. The $i$'th interval is decomposed into subintervals of length $y_1,y_2-y_1,\ldots,y_i-y_{i+1}$.

Altogether, we obtain:

- $n$ subintervals of length $y_1$, appearing in intervals $1,\ldots,n$.
- $n-1$ subintervals of length $y_2-y_1$, appearing in intervals $2,\ldots,n$.
- $n-2$ subintervals of length $y_3-y_2$, appearing in intervals $3,\ldots,n$.
- And so on, until a single subinterval of length $y_n-y_{n-1}$, appearing in the $n$'th interval.

By assumption, if we sample $i$ according to this distribution, then the expected value of $a_i$ is exactly $v$. In particular, there must exist a subinterval length $y_j - y_{j-1}$ (where $y_0 = 0$) such that the expected value of $a_i$, *subject to the uniform point in $[0,1]$ falling inside a subinterval of this length*, is at least $v$. This expected value is exactly the average of $a_j,\ldots,a_n$.